# Refresh a Wix repeater when a new message is received

Tags: database, chat, velo

I have build a chatting system in Wix which consists of a repeater, an user Input, submit button, a database (Fields -  'senderId' 'recieverId' 'message') This is the working process ->

User A types something in the user Input.

Clicks Submit Button.

Inserts a new row in database.

User A's *dataset* refreshes.

**At the same time User B's dataset should also refresh**

How can I help myself ??
Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repeater is connected to a dataset then keep refreshing the dataset on a loop under your page's onReady function.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    setInterval( () => {
        $w("#dataset").refresh();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Note that if you need custom filtering you may want to use a [setFilter()](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-dataset/dataset/setfilter) function instead of a direct refresh.